# Convolution neural network: small dataset affecting accuracy

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, convolution

I have dataset of 36 folders 1 image each(total 36 images) the dataset is too small but these are character images which i want to train my `val_acc= 0.0229` and `y_pred=model.predict(x_test)` always predict `class=4`.

How I can improve this accuracy for such a small dataset? Why does it always predict class 4?

Comment: Your goal may be better served by using your time and effort to collect additional data samples and/or reconsidering your desire to use a neural network.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you have 36 class and 1 sample/class. 
Then I believe it's impossible to use Machine Learning for this dataset to predict the label.

Reason: When you split train/test set, there will some classes that only appear in test set and not train set. The model doesn't learn about them at all. A major assumption in Machine Learning problems is that the train set and test set must have the same statistical distribution.

Comment: what if i copy multiple times each image inside folder for example now its 1 image in 1 folder so i make 400 copies of that image would it be wrong

Comment: If all the images in one class are the same, then your model probably just memorizes the images, not learns anything. Currently I still don't understand your problem. If you want to recognize some characters, collect more images of these characters to train your model. There's also one-shot learning algorithms that permit you to learn from one image. But you still need to have sample of each class in both train and test set. It's impossible to do that if you have only 1 image/class.

Comment: i have 36 total characters (means 37 classes) which i want to train for individual character recognition. if i add 3 more images from different fonts then it might be able to learn what u think? also please answer that y it always predict class-4

Comment: You could try to train on all the data if you can live with the fact that you will never really know the performance accuracy.  I would lose sleep over this since any model you build is basically guaranteed to perform badly given how little data you have.